# How do I replace line-by-line text of a file in C?

Tags: c, file, read-write

I have been researching this for a while and haven't been able to find anything that helps my specific case.

I have a function in which I need to encrypt text in a file. What I want to do is to read a line from a text file and store it into a string, run an encryption algorithm on the string and write the encrypted content of the string back into to the file. That is, I want to replace the file's current line with the encrypted line.

Here is what I have so far:

```
int encrypt_file(char file_name[]) {
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r+");

    if (file) {
        char line[300];
        while ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) != NULL) {
            fseek(file, -(strlen(line)), SEEK_CUR);
            encrypt_string(line);
            if (fputs(line, file) == EOF) {
                printf("Error. Please try again.\n");
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Error. Ensure file exists and try again.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

To explain my logic, I read the line from the file and then use `fseek` to move the pointer back by however many characters were read (it should now be at the beginning of the line). I then run the algorithm and then write the new string back into the file.

However, this code gives me an infinite loop.  When I remove the `fseek`, it doesn't give me an infinite loop and it shows me that the algorithm has been correctly used on the string, but it shows the `"Error. Please try again.\n"` response and no changes have been made to the file itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user3121023 It's closer to the expected output, but still not quite there. The file contains the text:

`Hello\n`
`Bye`

The output after running the program should be:

`Khoor\n`
`Ebh`

but the output currently is:

`HKhoor\n`
`eh`

(Imagine the text after \n is on a new line)

Comment: @user3121023 I did that, it seems to reads the `Hello` on the first line correctly, but outputs `Khoor` after the `H` so that the end result in the file is `HKhoor`. For some reason, it then skips the first character (`B`) in the next line and goes straight to `ye`. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are on Windows, you should be aware that in a text file a newline is represented with TWO bytes, but in a string read from it it's ONE byte. Because of this zillion year old quirk, `fseek`ing in a text file on Windows is not *boring*.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. - on Windows you can specify the "b" (binary) mode modifier when calling `fopen` which suspends the \r\n -> \n translation behavior, assuming the runtime library you're using supports it.

Comment: Don't do this.  Seriously, don't do this.  The logic is much, much, much simpler if you read from one file and write to another.  If you want to make the original path a link to the new file when you're done, then relink it.  From the user's perspective, it behaves exactly the same as if you had actually overwritten the file. Unless you care about breaking other hard links (you probably don't), this is a better approach.  And if you do care, it's easier to write to another file and then overwrite the original when done.  Rule of thumb: if you call fseek, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an answer posted here that helped solve my issue. I'm not sure why it has been deleted but if anyone was wondering, it was suggested that I use `ftell` to keep track of where the pointer should be. This is the code I have now, and it works as intended (the `#ifdef` statements were just to find out what was going wrong, and are not necessary for the code to work):

```
int encrypt_file (char file_name[]) {
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r+");
    long fileindex = 0;

    if (file) {
        char line[300];
        while ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) != NULL) {
            #ifdef DEBUG
                printf("Input: %s", line);
                char* p = strchr(line, '\n');
                if (!p) {
                    printf("\n");
                }
            #endif

            fseek(file, fileindex, SEEK_SET);
            encrypt_string(line);

            #ifdef DEBUG
                printf("Output: %s\n", line);
            #endif

            if (fputs(line, file) == EOF) {
                printf("Error. Please try again.\n");
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
            fileindex = ftell(file);
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("Error. Ensure file exists and try again.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why @user3121023 deleted his correct answer, but here are 2 points worth mentioning: one must issue a positioning request between read and write operations on a stream open in updated mode. This explains the need for  `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);` which looks like a no-op. Also this method only works if the `encrypt_string()` function that modifies its string argument does not change its length, and in particular does not generate null bytes. It would probably be safer to open the file in `"rb+"` mode.